# Error with php number_format

Tags: php

I get this error `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, object given in /home/rainingt/public_html/quadhits/index.php on line 165` from one of my exchange sites. But Does not get it from a different webhost. What can be the problem, when the 2 sites are from the same script?

```
<tr>
    <td style="color: black">Pages shown today</td>
    <td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: <?=number_format($C->sfrfv('sum(num)', '7statsite', 'where date="'.date('Y-m-d').'"'), 0, '', ' ')?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: black">Pages yesterday</td>
    <td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: <?=number_format($C->sfrfv('sum(num)', '7statsite', 'where date="'.date('Y-m-d', time() - 86400).'"'), 0, '', ' ')?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    (page165)<td style="color: black">Unique surfers today</td>
<td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: <?= number_format( $C->sfrfv('count(usrid)', '7stat', 'where date="'.date('Y-m-d').'" group by date'), 0, '', ' ')?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: black">Unique surfers yesterday</td>
<td style="color: #336699; font-weight: bold">: <?=number_format($C->sfrfv('count(usrid)', '7stat', 'where date="'.date('Y-m-d', time() - 86400).'" group by date'), 0, '', ' ')?>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is this function: `$C->sfrfv()` doing? Can you post the code for it

Comment: Does `$C->sfrfv()` return double?

Comment: There is an error in your code, specifically in the `$C->sfrfv` function. The fact that you're seeing the error on one host but not the other is due to different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can be set to disable warnings (in php.ini), which is why the two webhosts behave differently. You can read more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

As to removing the warnings, you can do two things. You can make `$C->sfrfv()` return a double, or you can cast the return as a double in each call by doing something like this: `(double)$C->sfrfv()` (assuming it's supposed to return a number).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `</td>` on the offending line+1, but that shouldn't trigger an error like that. You might try removing the extra spaces (before number_format and $C, as compared to the lines without errors), and see if it helps. I can't see any other differences that could account for the error. Extra spaces *shouldn't* have an effect, but who knows?

The error message implies that $C is being returned, as an object, rather than a numeric result from its method sfrfv(). What if you omit the number_format() and just output the raw number... what shows up then?

I would definitely make sure you're getting the same level of error messages on both systems (per SuperTron), and make sure you're not overlooking a bogus value return silently being turned from an object into a number.